# If statement hack, is there is better way to write this?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am taking an experimental first shot at writing a simple side-scroller game. I have this code for re-centering the screen if the player moves too far in some direction.

Is there a better way to write it? I feel like I am abusing the language, but it worked out so nicely that I think it might be okay.

```
public void adjustFrameIfNecessary()
{
    int dx, dy;
    if ((dx = (GAME_WIDTH - GAME_WIDTH / 3) - player.x) < 0 || (dx = GAME_WIDTH / 3 - player.x) > 0 || (dx = 0) == 0);
    if ((dy = (GAME_HEIGHT - GAME_HEIGHT / 3) - player.y) < 0 || (dy = GAME_HEIGHT / 3 - player.y) > 0 || (dy = 0) == 0);

    if(dx != 0 || dy != 0)
    {
        for (Drawable shiftMe : drawables)
        {
            shiftMe.unconditionalShift(dx, dy);
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

With regards to everyone's input, in an attempt to make it more readable, I have changed it to this

```
public void adjustFrameIfNecessary()
{
    int dx, dy;

    assignX:
    {
        dx = (GAME_WIDTH - GAME_WIDTH / 3) - player.x;
        if(dx < 0) break assignX;
        dx = GAME_WIDTH / 3 - player.x;
        if(dx > 0) break assignX;
        dx = 0;
    }

    assignY:
    {
        dy = (GAME_HEIGHT - GAME_HEIGHT / 3) - player.y;
        if(dy < 0) break assignY;
        dy = GAME_HEIGHT / 3 - player.y;
        if(dy > 0) break assignY;
        dy = 0;
    }

    if (dx != 0 || dy != 0)
    {
        for (Drawable shiftMe : drawables)
        {
            shiftMe.unconditionalShift(dx, dy);
        }
    }

}
```

Is this better?

**EDIT 2**

```
public void adjustFrameIfNecessary()
{
    int dx = calculateShift(GAME_WIDTH, frameReference.x);
    int dy = calculateShift(GAME_HEIGHT, frameReference.y);

    if (dx != 0 || dy != 0)
    {
        for (Drawable shiftMe : drawables)
        {
            shiftMe.unconditionalShift(dx, dy);
        }
    }
}
```

I think that it is clear now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Yes, burying multiple assignments inside an `if` conditional is difficult to read, and is therefore going to be difficult to maintain in the future.  You should try to avoid that.

Comment: in the recent years i changed my coding style to be more naive. and this is exactly the advice i would give you: write programs so that your code reflects your intentions as directly as possible. no user of an application ever complained that the source is longer than necessary, and i don't think many programmers do this either. no need to cram as much as possible into a single line. even though i have to admit it feels great, i still don't suggest doing it :) p.s. the second version is worse by a lot.

Comment: Have to agree, the second version is not even anymore readable and it's more verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unreadable, but I get your point. One thing, though: why not reuse the same check for both x and y? And by using the ternary operator you get one hack less.

```
static int toBounds(int max, int curr) {
  int ret;
  return ((ret = (max - max/3) - curr) < 0 || (ret = max/3 - curr) > 0)? ret : 0;
}
```

Comment: `GAME_WIDTH` and `GAME_HEIGHT` are not necessarily the same.

Comment: This is a function you'll call twice: first time with `GAME_WIDTH`, second time with `GAME_HEIGHT.

Comment: I think a function call is too expensive. This method is called so often that I want at little overhead as possible. Unless there is some way that I can guarantee the java compiler will make it inline, then I wouldn't want to do this.

Comment: There will be no function call once HotSpot inlines it. You really should NOT go for that level of optimization. Just make sure it's a static method to make HotSpot's decision easier. Or make it a private method. These are practically guaranteed to get inlined.

Comment: maybe look at my solution. i like where this is going, but i think in this very case making it a tad bit more abstract clears these weird ```x/3```, makes the code more understandable and in fact gives you a function that should be useful in different places as well (you know... the kind of function that you can _actually_ copy&paste to another project)

Comment: @nullUser - How about you confirm there is overhead before you worry about the possability of said overhead.  This code is a great deal better then what you originaly had and even better then code you modified because you realized how horrible the code you had was.

Comment: @Ramhound I think I have a fundamentally different programming ideology than you. I have spent too much time in the past rewriting old code because I didn't consider how expensive function calls are. I would rather make extensive comments about why the code works than hope the compiler will optimize out some slowness.

Comment: nullUser, just make sure that when you consider manually inlining code, you know exactly how expensive it is. I think I've read that an unoptimized virtual function call costs around 10 machine instructions (could be less). Now, the function above is itself quite a bit more than 10 instructions, so the call is already getting drowned by it. Second, your game would have to call that function at the very least **a million times per second** to be able to discern even the slightest difference between an inlined an non-inlined call.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand why you have those `if` statements at the top at all. You should simply assign the variables when you initialize them.

```
dx = (GAME_WIDTH - GAME_WIDTH / 3) - player.x)
dy = (GAME_HEIGHT - GAME_HEIGHT / 3) - player.y)
```

They're going to be assigned to that regardless in your `if` statement. If it rearches the third condition then it already *is* zero, so there is no reason to assign it. discard the two `if` statements and instead stick to just straight variable assignment. Keep the condition above the `for` loop, that is the only check you need to make.

Comment: You have missed the subtlety of that code, which just proves how readable it is.

Comment: If it reaches the third block of the if it doesn't have to be zero... Look more closely at the if, it isn't symmetric.

Comment: Plus the first two comparisons are not at all the same.

Answer (score 4):

Your if statements are confusing to read. If you (or anyone else) need to change it at a later time, it might be very difficult and error prone.

It is a good habit to make code that not only works, but is maintainable. Since you got it to work, you should make it more maintainable.

Break the if statements in to variables that makes sense and use multiple lines. You aren't writing for a golf code contest?

You'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
/* calculate offset to center */
dx = X_current_center - player.x;
dy = Y_current_center - player.y;

if (abs(dx) > MARGIN || abs(dy) > MARGIN)
    /* recenter */
```

Comment: i think MARGIN would be GAME_WIDTH/6. but note that you still have to compute _how far_ you want to shift. so in a way it's avoiding the original question.

Comment: @kritzikratzi the point here is to show that you don't need to use nested ifs but assign the values and depending on the values do the action. The question of recentering I would put that into a separate function called recenter. depending on what you want: always center the player (easy) or split up the area in quadrants calculate the quadrant and make a switch based on the quadrant.

Comment: i hear you, but figuring out whether recentering is required and to what extent it is required are very much the same computations. i myself wouldn't tear those two appart ...

Answer (score 1):

the idea to improve such code is usually to use math :)

first of all, sorry for the long post. if you ever meet me in person don't ask me about this topic, i won't stop talking.

### short version

do this:

```
/**
 * Computes the distance from a point x to an interval [a,b]
 */
public static int distanceToInterval( int x, int a, int b ){
   return x<a? (a-x): ( x>b? (b-x):0 ); 
   // alternative: 
   // return Math.max( a - x, 0 ) + Math.min( b - x, 0 ); 
}

// then use as 
int dx = distanceToInterval( player.x, GAME_WIDTH/3, GAME_WIDTH*2/3 ); 
int dy = distanceToInterval( player.y, GAME_HEIGHT/3, GAME_HEIGHT*2/3 );
```

### long version

**your initial statement**

```
if ((dx = (GAME_WIDTH - GAME_WIDTH / 3) - player.x) < 0 || 
    (dx = GAME_WIDTH / 3 - player.x) > 0 || 
    (dx = 0) == 0);
```

this can be cleaned up a bit by making it into a ...

**...longer version**

```
dx1 = GAME_WIDTH*2/3 - player.x; 
dx2 = GAME_WIDTH*1/3 - player.x; 
dx3 = 0; 

if( dx1 < 0 ) dx = dx1; 
else if( dx2 > 0 ) dx = dx2; 
else dx = dx3;
```

this is imho a lot clearer. i can now see what you're trying to do and put it in a neat sentence: 
*if the player is not inside the center third of the screen, we'd like to move the screen*

**make it even more clear**

```
if( player.x < GAME_WIDTH/3 ) dx = GAME_WIDTH/3 - player.x;  // positive num
else if( player.x > GAME_WIDTH*2/3 ) dx = GAME_WIDTH*2/3 - player.x; // negative num
else dx = 0; // no shift
```

you can see i reordered your statement, i check the left boundary first, then the right one. if you come a country that reads from right to left you might find the other direction more intuitive :)

*THIS* is the solution i would pick. 
it's short, it's readable, it's perfect :)

however, if you want it more concise you could go a step further

**do the math tricks**

you need to understand that the three cases are completely exclusive, they can't ever happen at the same time. let's go back to using more variables:

```
// on the left side we shift a positive number, or not at all 
dx1 = Math.max( GAME_WIDTH/3 - player.x, 0 ); 
// on the right side we shift a negative amount, or not at all 
dx2 = Math.min( GAME_WIDTH*2/3 - player.x, 0 );
```

now look at the beauty of this:

- if `GAME_WIDTH/3-player.x > 0`, then `GAME_WIDTH*2/3 - player.x > 0` 
  thus `Math.min(...,0) = 0`
- if `GAME_WIDTH*2/3 - player.x < 0`, then `GAME_WIDTH*1/3 - player.x < 0`
  thus `Math.max(...,0) = 0`

this means you can simply add the two to compute the total shift. and this is what your code will look like:

```
int dx = 
     Math.max( GAME_WIDTH/3 - player.x, 0 ) + // too far to the left? 
     Math.min( GAME_WIDTH*2/3 - player.x, 0 ); // or too far to the right?
```

**a little more abstraction**

whatever variant you chose, it's now insanely easy to put this in a method. 
but let's make it a bit more meaningful than this special case. i would suggest

```
/**
 * Computes the distance from a point x to an interval [a,b]
 */
public static int distanceToInterval( int x, int a, int b ){
   return 
       Math.max( a - x, 0 ) + // too far to the left? 
       Math.min( b - x, 0 ); // or too far to the right? 
}

// now use as 
int dx = distanceToInterval( player.x, GAME_WIDTH/3, GAME_WIDTH*2/3 ); 
int dy = distanceToInterval( player.y, GAME_HEIGHT/3, GAME_HEIGHT*2/3 );
```

---

*p.s. please note that i've replaced `GAME_WIDTH - GAME_WIDTH/3` by `GAME_WIDTH*2/3` throughout this post. these two give slightly different results with integer math, but i just prefer the short version as i find it more intuitive ("two thirds of the screen" vs "the entire screen and then one third back").*

Comment: maybe i start to obsess about this question too much, but: assume you already have the very common clamp function, i.e. 
```public static int clamp( int x, int a, int b ){ return x < a? a : (x>b?b:x); }```
this will always give you a value inside the interval [a,b]. 
either a value is inside the interval, in this case ```clamp(x)=x```. or it is outside the interval, in this case the difference between the original value and the clamped value is exactly the shift you're looking for. 
```public int distanceToInterval( int x, int a, int b ){ return clamp( x, a, b ) - x; }```

Comment: Unfortunately I must say that none of this is an undisputed improvement. You slightly vary the degrees of freedom, rewrite expressions to about equally long other expressions... in the end it's still a matter of personal preference which version to pick.

Comment: neither are short expressions favorable, nor was that part of the question. anyways, also there is an undisputed difference between readability and one-liners (maybe it's just not as important to you as it is to me :) )

Comment: I kind of like the last one, but it should be parameterized with frame dimension and margin instead of interval.

Comment: oh, yes :) that's my mathematical background i guess ... (math just seems to have terms for all of these basic things)

Comment: No, I mean change the API not to accept interval boundaries, but instead the data natural to the problem domain: frame size, margin. There's a simple transformation between those two.

Comment: i hear you, but i disagree. in my mind math IS the language of the problem domain. it's not that there is a library with solveThisProblem() methods for such specific things. ultimately, when it comes to programming and graphics you can't escape maths.

Comment: But what makes the (frameSize, margin) pair not qualified as "maths", whereas (lower bound, upper bound) is qualified? The first one is just more naturally adapted to the problem domain. It is obvious from your function call example: you can see that you need to go to the extra trouble of adapting the problem domain's parameters to the function's. Imagine having 100 such calls in an app, all having to duplicate that transformation. That's bad API design.

Comment: i'm not sure how many adjustFrameIfNecessary methods you think a game has, but i suppose it's quite accurately a single one.

Comment: So you're copping out with an excuse. You have developed a whole lecture on good code design and now your argument is that in this particular situation it's not going to get called more than once? In that case there is no justification for a method in the first place, let alone one that isn't even a perfect match to that one place it is used in. You're splitting the work between the caller and the callee.

Comment: let me be frank: i gave the problem some thought, actually analyzed what the intention of the code was and found that there is an underlying, insanely easy, mathematical concept; namely the distance of a value to a 1d-interval. 
you reproduced the same unreadable mess that the OP had but pulled it out into a method and renamed the variables to make it even less readable. end of discussion, for me at least. bye.

Comment: You certainly gave it a lot more thought than I did, or that the question called for. I fail to see the relevance of that to this point in discussion, though. It's all about **your** solution, which you kindly asked me to have a look at. I took that as an invitation from your part to give you my thoughts. If you didn't want my opinion, why did you leave that comment under my question?